# First derivate of NDVI time-series modelled with phenex spline and double logistic curve fitting

Tags: r, spline, derivative

I'm modelling NDVI time series from MODIS terra and Sentinel 2 data. 
In order to get continuous NDVI values (needed to draw inferences on the plant phenology) I fitted curves to my data with the aid of the package `phenex` (`modelNDVI` function). The methods "spline" and "Double logistic" perform best so far, which is in line with respective literature, so no problems there.

I now want to calculate the change in NDVI over time in order to get measures for the rate of change in biomass. This can be achieved by calculating the first derivative of a NDVI time series (values scaled between 0 and 1). I therefore need to derive the function which I used to model the NDVI values. And that's where it all gets a little precarious. Here is what I did so far:

I took the source code of the two `modelNDVI` methods from `phenex`

#### Spline

```
spline <- function(ndvi){
      days <- length(ndvi)

      f <- splinefun(x=(-days+1):(2*days), y=c(ndvi,ndvi,ndvi), method="monoH.FC")
      ndvi.interpol <- f(1:days)

      ndvi.interpol[which(ndvi.interpol < 0)] <- 0
      ndvi.interpol[which(ndvi.interpol > 1)] <- 1

      return(ndvi.interpol)
    }
```

#### Double logistic

```
DL <- 
  function(ndvi){
    days <- length(ndvi)

    time <- which(!is.na(ndvi)) 
    ndvi <- ndvi[time]

    Wt <- function(vb,ve,k,p,d,c,q, time) {
      erg <- vb + (k/(1+exp(-c*(time-p)))) - ((k+vb-ve)/(1+exp(-d*(time-q))))
      return(erg)
    }

    Wx <- function(x, time, ndvi){
      erg <- sum((Wt(vb=x[1], ve=x[2], k=x[3], p=x[4], d=x[5], c=x[6], q=x[7], time)-ndvi)^2)
      return(ifelse((is.infinite(erg)||is.nan(erg)),1e50,erg))
    }


    model <- DEoptim(fn=Wx, time=time, ndvi=ndvi,
                     lower=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                     upper=c(1,1,1,days,1,1,days),
                     control=list(VTR=0, strategy=1, NP=200, itermax = 200, trace=FALSE, CR=0.9))

    vb <- model$optim$bestmem[1]
    ve <- model$optim$bestmem[2]
    k <- model$optim$bestmem[3]
    p <- model$optim$bestmem[4]
    d <- model$optim$bestmem[5]
    c <- model$optim$bestmem[6]
    q <- model$optim$bestmem[7]
    model.interpol <- Wt(vb,ve,k,p,d,c,q, time=1:days) 

    return(model.interpol)
  }
```

I have tried the following to get the first derivative of the corresponding function:

```
 f <- splinefun(x=(-days+1):(2*days), y=c(ndvi,ndvi,ndvi), method="monoH.FC")
          ndvi.interpol <- f(1:days, deriv = 1)
```

[image: Graph of spline curve and curve of first derivative thereof]

and for DL with package `Deriv`

```
Wt <- function(vb,ve,k,p,d,c,q, time) {
vb + (k/(1+exp(-c*(time-p)))) - ((k+vb-ve)/(1+exp(-d*(time-q))))
}
Deriv(Wt)
```

[image: graph of DL curve and first derivative thereof]

I fed the output from the console back to the function and ran it again. Unfortunately the values for the rate of change in biomass I get don't seem to be very convincing for (Spline very small values and DL very high values) either of the functions. I'm not the greatest mathematician, therefore any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Did you draw graphs of your predicted functions to see if something looks off?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I did draw graphs, linked them. Hope this works...my reputation is not good enough to embed them directly :)